# ParserError: Expected primary expression

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, ether

Following is my code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.17;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor () public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint256) {
        returns unit(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
    }


}
```

And I am getting following error:

```
browser/ballot.sol:17:9: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
        returns unit(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
        ^-----^
```

Current version is 0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.Emscripten.clang

How to resolve this error?

Comment: What is `unit`???

Comment: Hey man! I know it's been two years already, but I believe Rosco Kalis gave you a valid answer don't you think? Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The keyword you have to use to return a value is `return`, not `returns`. And as goodvibration mentioned, you probably meant to write `uint`, instead of `unit`. The following should work:

```solidity
function random() private view returns (uint256) {
    return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
}
```